# GridView As ListView Cell not Showing All Items

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I wanted to make a gridview with images cell to show some image collections in my app within aMain listview the code is just working fine and the images is showing in the listview but the problem is all the cells shows only 2 images (2 columns which i already specified in gridview layout) while i have filled my gridview list with 5 images !!

her is my layouts :

Main ListView,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.mtids.gridviewaslistviewcell.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/LV" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the GridView layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/cgrid" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and the Imageview cell layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/cimage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

any ideas will be much appreciated

[image]

Comment: Did you try removing the numColumns from Grid View ?

Comment: You can refer to this url :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27353336/5860087

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 0):

You need following things to use gridview , listview -

1) Layout containing Gridview or ListView
2) Layout for GridView or ListViewItem (Single item)
3) Adapter for binding data to listView or GridView

Now you may try with   **android:columnWidth="any value as you like (dp)"** ,   **android:numColumns="auto_fit"** , **android:stretchMode="columnWidth"** on GridView.

Documentation   https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html